# Showing progress of long-running PHP script using jQuery progressbar

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, progress-bar

Sometimes jQuery's documentation makes me feel dumb as a post.

I have an application that uses PHP on the server to process the creation of multiple orders (sometimes over a thousand).  I'm trying to figure out how to have that script (called via $.ajax) notify the UI of its status.

I understand the .onprogress, .success, and .complete elements in $.ajax, but I cannot find an example of what the PHP script should be doing to feed data to each of those event types.

In old-school javascript, using ajax.readyState, you can grab PHP.echo() events from the script for progress purposes, then use the PHP.exit() event to complete the request.

How does one do that in a $.ajax world?

Many thanks from an old dog trying to learn new tricks.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out the brute-force way.

Each time you echo() from the server side, the bundle is passed to the onprogress handler as e.target.responseText.  Note that responseText continues to grow with each response, so you'll need a client-side variable to keep track of its prior length:

```
var this_str, last_len = 0;
...
onprogress: function (e) {
    this_str = e.target.responseText.substr(last_len);
    ...do something with this_str...
    last_len = e.target.responseText.length;
}
...
```

If the result is json, you'll need to decode this_str (not responseText).  That works best with a different technique, because depending on the frequency of updates from the server your parse may get overloaded.  Since you're sending json objects, the entire responseText string is a series of json objects, delimited by closing- and opening-curly braces "}{".  So break it into parts, and use the latest:

```
var subtext, parts, json;
...
onprogress: function (e) {
    parts = e.target.responseText.split('}{');
    if (parts.length > 1) {
        subtext = '{' + parts[parts.length - 1];
    } else {
        subtext = parts[0];
    }
    json = JSON.parse(subtext);
    ...
```

The success function uses a similar approach for json:

```
success: function (text) {
    parts = text.split('}{');
    if (parts.length > 1) {
        subtext = '{' + parts[parts.length - 1];
    } else {
        subtext = parts[0];
    }
    json = JSON.parse(subtext);
    ...
```

Note that there will be a couple of not-useful onprogress events as things get started; be sure to test for those and ignore them.

When your server-side function terminates or exit()s, both your success function and onprogress function will receive the full responseText string.  If you want to do something different in success, remember to keep track of the final string in responseText.